# Вообще, вообще-то, вообще говоря

Tags: пунктуация, вводные-слова

В разных источниках (ПАС, Розенталь, словарь Кузнецова, Справочник по пунктуации) информация относительно этих слов **не всегда совпадает**.

Всего обозначены три функции: **наречие, частица, вводное слово**,  с семантикой тоже далеко не всё ясно. Также не объясняется, чем частица отличается от наречия.

Вопросы такие:

1) **Как меняется смысл предложения**, если в нем использовать слова ***вообще, вообще-то, вообще говоря*** в трех названных функциях?

2) **Сколько всего вариантов** с разным смыслом, разными функциями и разной пунктуацией возможно?

Предложение в качестве примера: *Мне этот проект **вообще (вообще-то, вообще говоря)** не нравится.*

Answer (score 2):

Едва ли возможно "непотопляемое" обобщение (смыслы многообразны в разных контекстах), но с конкретным примером разобраться несложно. В варианте "**...вообще не нравится**" имеет место *наречие* со значением "совсем" (нисколько). Во "вводном" варианте с "**вообще-то**" (= вопреки чему-то - мнению собеседника, ранее высказанному своему и т. п. - в зависимости от внешнего контекста) содержится мягкая оговорка в пользу своего последнего мнения. Вводный оборот "**вообще говоря**" добавляет здесь смысл "не касаясь подробностей", "по сути своей". *Частица* появилась бы в случае "И **вообще** (= нечего меня тут убеждать), не нравится мне этот проект".

Comment: Спасибо, Александр, за ответ, определенная доля истины в нем есть, хотя нет обобщения. Конечно, не все смысловые значения могут присутствовать в одном конкретном предложении,  но в любом случае оно может быть оформлено неоднозначно и иметь разные оттенки смысла. Также хорошо бы найти точное определение частицы и наречия. У Лопатина частица не обособляется в предложении: Его ждали, а он вообще не приехал.

Comment: @Sharon Неужели вы бы обособили?

Answer (score 1):

1) Не могу согласиться. что всё в этой теме просто и ясно, **даже лингвисты не могут прийти к одному мнению,** и вот пример.

Слово ***вообще-то*** в "Справочнике по пунктуации" считается **вводным словом и частицей,** а в ПАС – **вводным словом**, причем похожие примеры пишутся по-разному:

Справочник (частица): ***Вообще-то*** Елизавета Николаевна занимается с нами географией и естествознанием, **но** сегодня ...директор упросил ее заменить захворавшую Раису Ивановну. http://www.gramota.tv/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_89

ПАС (вводное слово): Он, ***вообще-то***, неправ, **но** говорит уверенно. http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=127#pp127

2) Разбор предложения: *Мне этот проект **вообще (вообще-то, вообще говоря)** не нравится.*

Я думаю, что в данном предложении можно выразить **два основных смысловых значения.**

**1) Абсолютное отрицание:**

*Мне этот проект **вообще**  не нравится.*

Будем считать, что это **наречие (не частица)**, но значение у слова **усилительное**: не нравится вообще: ни в целом, ни в частных деталях.

2) **Различные оттенки уступки**

Все эти оттенки можно выразить с помощью вводных слов ***вообще говоря, вообще-то.*** Они как раз и подразумевают, что нет абсолютного отрицания, и "смягчают" негативную оценку.

*Мне этот вариант проекта, **вообще говоря**, не нравится, так как он вряд ли окупится за короткое время.*

*Мне этот проект, **вообще-то говоря**, не нравится, в то же время в нем есть отдельные интересные детали.*

Именно частица ***то*** указывает, что оценка сделана только в общем плане, но затем делается переход к частным моментам.

Я думаю, что здесь возможны оба варианта (с обособлением и без обособления).

Comment: Правило всех редакций Москвы: *вообще-то* не обособляется НИКОГДА, даже за рупь.

Comment: Спасибо, интересно. Но правило-то правилом, но в Справочнике указана необособленная частица, и в Нацкорпусе много примеров без обособления. Ну вот первые попавшиеся: Вообще-то Таня не собиралась ехать в Москву, но получалось не совсем так, как хотелось (Л. Улицкая).Вообще-то слушать он никого не любил, а тут слушал… [Даниил Гранин] Куда он вообще-то запропал? ― поинтересовался Атаманов. [Василий Аксенов. ]